# Windows partition after installing Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, partitioning, windows

I installed Ubuntu on a computer with Windows 7. During installation, I chose the option to remove Windows 7. I had three partitions on my HDD: `C`,`D` and `E`. I thought Ubuntu would install the OS to the `C:/` drive. However, After installation, when I run Ubuntu I can't access partitions D and E anymore.

I would like to know if my old partitions are gone or deleted by Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Ubuntu by selecting the *Remove Windows 7 and install Ubuntu* option will wipe your Hard Drive and create a separate type of file system and partition system.

You will no longer have a C, D, and E drives.

So the Windows partitions are deleted along with any data they had in them and a new single partition of whole hard Disk is created.